# Pickerview content not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, string, view, uipickerview

I'm trying to get a picker view with a list of numbers in it.

So far I can get the string to hold all the numbers, but when it comes to putting it in the picker view the picker view is always empty. Can you please look at my code and let me know where I'm going wrong?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PickerView: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var questionNumberPickers: UIPickerView!

    var Category: String!
    var numbDict: String!
    var QuestionNumber: String!
    var cell: UITableViewCell?
    var currentTopicIndex = Int()
    var setCount = Int()
    var setNumber = Int()
    var pickerString2 = [String]()
    var selectedQuestionNumber: String!
    var contacts: NSArray?
    var dictContacts = Int()
    var pickerArray: NSArray?

    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfRow: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(currentTopicIndex)

        questionNumberPickers.delegate = self
        questionNumberPickers.dataSource = self

        self.numberOfRow.text = "0"
        setCount = Quiz.quizzes[currentTopicIndex].plist.count

        let min = 1
        let max = setCount
        let intArray: [Int] = Array(min...max)
        print(intArray)

        let pickerString2 = intArray.map
        {
            String($0)
        }

        self.questionNumberPickers?.reloadAllComponents()

        print(pickerString2)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "questionToQuiz"){

            //   Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
            let detailScene = segue.destination as! QuizController


            detailScene.numberOfQuestions = numberOfRow.text as String!
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerString2.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerString2[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        numberOfRow.text  = pickerString2[row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing thank you EmirC! Your a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "let" from let pickerString2 = intArray.map
        {
            String($0)
        }

In viewDidLoad you are initializing a second variable named pickerString2.

```
let pickerString2 = intArray.map
    {
        String($0)
    }
```

it should be like

```
pickerString2 = intArray.map
    {
        String($0)
    }
```

But you are trying to fill the pickerview with the other pickerString2 variable which is empty.

```
var pickerString2 = [String]()
```